# How to avoid memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a question on memory leak. Probably a basic one.

```
map_a is an map of <int, vector<int>*>
ptr is an pointer to an vector of ints.
```

Inside for loop, I am searching for 'element' in map_a. If pointer is not found, then create a new vector/record in map_a.

C++ pseudo-code:

```
map map_a;
for ( 1 to 10 ) {
  element = <int number come from a different algorithm, diff every time>;
  vector<int> *ptr = map_a[element];
  if (!ptr) {
    ptr = new vector<int>;
    map[element] = ptr;
  }
  ptr->push_back(i);
}
```

How to free up the memory we are allocation using new? I am sure that we may be having alternate ways to achieve this situation. But how to take this code along? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Do you really need to dynamically allocate a vector? I would avoid the leak by avoiding the dynamic allocation of the vector.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.

Comment: Don't use `new`, if you need to allocate, use `make_unique`/`make_shared`.

Comment: @drescherjm. I wish I could. But how would have you done it anyway?

Comment: @Poriferous Tell me, why?

Comment: @Jarod42, This is something which I heard just now. May be I will try to follow it later. Thanks.

Comment: I would do it without using new. Change your map to use vectors not pointers to vectors.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using raw pointers; smart pointers aren't the issue here. The issue is that he's creating a temporary pointer which gets destroyed when the for loop ends. Because `ptr` gets destroyed, what's contained within `map[element]` is a dangling pointer. Smart pointers can't resolve that.

Comment: @Poriferous this is not at all true. ptr points to a dynamically allocated memory and the only thing getting destroyed will be the pointer, the memory will not be deallocated.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Absolutely correct.

Comment: @HemantBhargava one problem with your pseudocode is that it doesn't make sense to write a loop like that. E.g., you only ever access `map_a[5]`. So, it's hard to tell what you're actually trying to achieve. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us help you.

Comment: @Poriferous, now take back your -1 vote. :)

Comment: @mindriot. 5 is actually not fixed number. It would keep chaning with every iteration.
I should have actually cleared it in question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HemantBhargava although what is stated by Poriferous is wrong, the question still is very low quality. It is not clear what you want to achieve. If what you want to know is how to use dynamically allocated vector then leave just that section, if you want something else edit the question in a way that we can understand it

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer in c++ is deallocated just the same way. So if you have a pointer to a vector you can call delete like so:

```
vector<int> *a = new vector<int>();
delete a;
```

However I think that most probably there is a better solution to whatever you are trying to do than using a dynamically allocated vector.

EDIT: from your question it is not apparent if the map is empty before the cycle. If it is you can simply iterate over it and call delete for each of its values:

```
for (auto it = map_a.begin(); it != map_a.end(); ++it) {
  delete it->second.
}
```

However if the map is not empty you will need an auxilary container (say a vector) to store the pointers allocated in this cycle:

```
map map_a;
vector<vector<int> * > allocated;
for ( 1 to 10 ) {
  element = <int number come from a different algorithm, diff every time>;
  vector<int> *ptr = map_a[element];
  if (!ptr) {
    ptr = new vector<int>;
    allocated.push_back(ptr);
    map[element] = ptr;
  }
  ptr->push_back(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < allocated.size(); ++i) {
   delete allocated[i];
}
```